# cent os 7 alwayson primary is in resolving state and not going to secondary

Tags: availability-groups

I have configured AlwaysOn in external mode between two CentOS 7 VMs. 
When manual failover happens, primary goes to resolving state. It never turns to secondary and secondary is always in secondary state

-- All nodes (linux01 and linux02)

```
sudo pcs property set stonith-enabled=false 
sudo pcs property set no-quorum-policy=ignore 
sudo pcs property set cluster-recheck-interval=2min
```

-- resource configuration

```
sudo pcs resource create sqlag ocf:mssql:ag ag_name=haag master notify=true meta failure-timeout=30s 
sudo pcs resource create vip_ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 ip=192.168.52.62 cidr_netmask=24 op monitor interval=30s

sudo pcs constraint colocation add vip_ip  sqlag-master INFINITY with-rsc-role=Master

sudo pcs constraint order promote sqlag-master then start vip_ip

sudo pcs cluster start --all
```

-- linux01 is primary move to linux02

```
sudo pcs resource move sqlag-master linux02 --master
```

linux01 in resolving; linux02 in secondary. Hangs; no response in SSMS.